# What are the values of m and n?

Tags: linear-algebra

When the polynomial $P(x)= 3x^3 + mx^2 + nx -7$ is divided by $x - 2$ , the reminder is $-3$ .
When the polynomial is divided by $x + 1$ , the reminder is $-18$ . What are the values of $m$ and $n$ .

Comment: Do you know the [remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem)?

Comment: Hint: The remainders are the values of $P(2)$ and $P(-1)$. This gives you two linear equations in $m$ and $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply remainder theorem

Put $X$ equal to $2$ and in place of $p(2)$ put $-3$

Similarly for the other case also.

Put $X=-1$ and $p(-1)$ as -$18$..

And solve the two...

Answer (score 0):

$$P(x)=q_1(x)(x-2)-3 \Rightarrow P(2)=-3 \\ P(x)=q_2(x)(x+1)-18 \Rightarrow P(-1)=-18$$